# No space left on device: AH00023: Couldn't create the ssl-cache mutex

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, apache-2.4, apache2, httpd

I saw another similar questions here but none had a answer that solved this problem.

From time to time, around 3am, my Apache server freezes and i see those errors in my logs...

> (28) No space left on device: AH00023: Couldn't create the mpm-accept
> mutex

Does someone knows how to fix this?

**Another error part:**

> Failed to create ssl-cache . Configuration failed.

**Edit 2**

> ```
> > → ipcs -s | wc -l = 10
> > 
> > → sysctl kernel.msgmni = kernel.msgmni = 23630
> > 
> > → sysctl kernel.sem = kernel.sem = 250        32000   32      128
> ```

Comment: Free some disk space

Comment: Son, thats not the case. It happened with enough space available.

Comment: Hombre, what is the result of `df -h` and `df -i`?

Comment: Also what is the result of `ipcs -s | wc -l`?

Comment: And what is the result of `sysctl kernel.msgmni` and `sysctl kernel.sem`?

Comment: df -h/df -i shows not a single filesystem with more than 40% in use.

Comment: ipcs -s | wc -l tells me 10 - But i run a backup job at night around 1am-3am... Maybe the values go up around this time?

Comment: Try to exec this: `sysctl -w kernel.sem="250 32000 100 128"` and monitor apache for the error above

Comment: Ok... I'll let you know a few days from now the results, thanks!

Comment: The problem never happened again after executing that command @RomeoNinov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments seems like the default values of semaphors is not enough. Command:

```
sysctl -w kernel.sem="250 32000 100 128"
```

will increase the value of SEMOPM  (the maximum number of semaphore operations that can be performed per semop(2) system call (semaphore call)).
Do not forget to add such record in `/etc/sysctl.conf` to have the values set after reboot.